# Solaris Makefile Error

Tags: makefile, solaris

I am trying to build my project in solaris i686 and im getting error

> /usr/sfw/lib is incompatible with building a static executable.

I searched but could not find an answer.
The makefile im using is

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -g -Wall file.c -I$(header.h) -I$(file.a) -static -o NameOfExecutable
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Solaris 10, you can no more build a fully static executable as at least the C standard library (libc) is only available as a dynamically loaded shared object.

See https://blogs.oracle.com/rie/entry/static_linking_where_did_it